# Vim match closing bracket within brackets with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches everything except closing brackets or closing parentheses. Basically, something like this:

```
[^])]
```

However, I would assume that such an expression won't work, since the closing bracket would close the collection. Is that correct? I am a little confused with how vim's escaping system works with regular expressions, so I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it? Because it works. Make a document:

```
test[test]test
test(test)test
```

Then execute

```
:%s/[^])]//g
```

and you'll be left with

```
]
)
```

(I'm using `set magic` though, YMMV)

EDIT: In `set nomagic`, `\[^])]` will work.

This is not limited to `vim` - Ruby, for example, does the same thing. The key is to have the closing bracket as the first character in the class. The rationale is that you wouldn't have opened the character class if you didn't want to have at least one character in it, so you can match the closing bracket if it is first (after an optional negation operator).

Similarly, to match the caret `^`, it must not be the first character, and to match a dash `-`, it must be either first or last (it must be last if you want to also match `]`, which gets the first spot).

Comment: Alright, I must admit, I'm completely confused as to *why*. Could you please explain, or at least point me to some documentation that explains it?

Comment: @JakeKing: Added explanation.

Comment: Alright, great, thanks. I'm still a little bit confused about vim's regex escaping, though. For example, which characters need to be escaped and which don't? What if I don't want my `]` to be first? Would it be `[^)\]]`? Again, I'd be happy if I could just find some vim documentation that explains all this, but I'm not entirely sure where to look.

Comment: Here is the piece of vim documentation defining these rules: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#%5b%3abackspace%3a%5d

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to escape them with '\':

```
[^\])]
```

**Edit**: apparently it's not necessary in this case... And putting a '\' before ')' doesn't escape it but adds '\' to the unmatched chars. I would still escape ']' though...

**Edit 2**: the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#%5b%3abackspace%3a%5d) covers this case.

> To include a literal ']', '^', '-' or '\' in the collection, put 
>   a backslash before it: "[xyz\]]", "[\^xyz]", "[xy\-z]" and "[xyz\\]".
>   (Note: POSIX does not support the use of a backslash this way).  For
>   ']' you can also make it the first character (following a possible
>   "^"):  "[]xyz]" or "[^]xyz]" {not in Vi}.